# Options for approaching stable marriage problem with unequally sized sets of elements/preferences

Tags: algorithms, arrays, matching

I am looking for an algorithm/code that will provide stable matching for two unequally sized sets of elements (clubs and students) with an unequal set of preferences. There is a large pool of students looking to join a club, and a comparatively small pool of clubs for those students to join. Each student ranks only the clubs they wish to join in order of preference. In other words, each student will not be required to rank every club available. At the same time, each club has a maximum amount of students they can accept and this number differs across each club. Therefore, both pools for the algorithm are unequally sized, and each element within those pools (i.e. every individual club and student) could have a different number of preferences.

I have looked into the Gale-Shapley algorithm and envy-free matching, but I have not found any code that provides a stable match when there is so much variation in the elements/preferences. Does anyone know of any code that can accomplish this (preferably in something like Python or Java)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_with_indifference

Comment: Software libraries are off-topic here.